# Error: Predicting output using logistic regression in sas

Tags: machine-learning, sas, logistic-regression

I am a beginner in SAS. I am wondering if anyone can help with an issue that I facing predicting outpuut of a dataset using logistic regression in SAS.

I have a dataset "Census Income", the link for dataset is here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/census+income. It has 15 columns e.g. Age, Race, Occupation etc and the dependent variable is SalRange, which indicates if the salary of the individual is greater than or less than 50K per year.

I have created a model using training dataset and I am trying to predict values on a new dataset. The issue is that in the predicted dataset, outcomes/predicted values of many instances are missing. Following is the code that I am using:

```
/*loading the library containing the data */

libname sal '/folders/myfolders/';

/* training the model on census_training dataset */

proc logistic data=sal.census_training;
class Workplace Education Marital_Status Occupation Relationship Race Sex 
Native_country ;
model Salrange_num(event='0') = Age Fnlwgt Education_num Capital_gain 
Capital_Loss Hours_per_week Workplace Education Marital_Status Occupation 
Relationship    Race    Sex Native_country ;

/*scoring the model on a new dataset census_testing*/
score data=sal.census_testing out=sal.output 
priorevent=0.24081;
run;
```

I dont understand why a few of the observations wouldn't yield any predicted outcome. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

I am attaching a screenshot of my output for reference. Thanks in advance for the help everyone!
[Salary prediction output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg3nL.jpg)

Comment: Every variable has to be available for the data to be scored. The missing records likely have a missing value for one of the variables in the model.

Comment: Alternately there could be variables in the dataset to be scored with levels that are not in the training data.  For example if there was a country that wasn't in the training data you wouldn't be able to get predictions for it.